# Possible to use background gradient for D3.js graph connected to ticks on the x-axis?

Tags: d3.js

I'm looking to chart some time-based data over the course of multiple days (using a simple line chart). I'd like to present the time of day as a gradient of color in the background of the line graph. Noon of each day would be white, midnight is nearly black, and all other hours in between are a smooth greyscale in between.

I can do this very, very clunkily by drawing rectangles before my lines, but it has the following problems:
1. hours without a data point don't get a rectange, leaving a gap in my background
2. the transition is not smooth, but stepped

It seems that the best way to fill in the gaps would be to latch onto the ticks along the x-axis, as those are regularly spaced regardless of the data points.  Is there a way for me to apply a gradient, either CSS or SVG, along with the tick marks, that will smoothly flow from one to the other (that is, no gaps between where one gradient ends and the other begins, nor any overlap)?  If I add or remove data, the gradient should change accordingly.

Any and all assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, if you could add an example graph/image to your question it would help.

Answer (score 0):

just define the gradient in a `<def>` section, and place rectangles aligned with the days you are charting. set the fill attribute to `url("#the_gradient")`.
have a look here http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html